# Cuándo publico mi ampliación de .NET Framework en IIS de Windows no me deja Registrar ni Actualizar

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, crud

NET la verdad es que llevo varios días con el mismo problema, al momento de ejecutar mi aplicación en local me funciona todo, pero una vez que yo la publico en el servido IIS de Windows no me deja registrar, actualizar y eliminar, e intentado de muchas maneras pero es que aun no logro hacerlo bien, agradecería mucho su ayuda. Gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! ok.. y estan todos los permisos a la db, o lo que sea que estes usando, correctamente?

Comment: Hola Isaac, a tu pregunta la falta mas informacion, con lo que proporcionas, podriaser cualquier cosa, que no este el webconfig/appconfig en tu servidor, que no apunte correctamente a la base de datos, no tenga permisos etc. Lo mejor que puedes hacer es poner un try{}catch(){} en algun metodo en el que consultes, y cuando caiga al catch guardarlo en un log, ya sea el de windows o un archivo. asi podras obtener mas informacion acerca de que esta produciendo el error.